# Force git rename detection during merge even if file exists

Tags: git, merge, rename

I'm currently doing a massive refactoring of a Java application which splits service classes into service interfaces and service implementations, so for example

```java
package de.abc.def;
public class AuthenticationService {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("doing stuff");
    }
}
```

becomes

```java
package de.abc.def;
public interface AuthenticationService {
    void doStuff();
}

package de.abc.impl;
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements de.abc.def.AuthenticationService {
    @Override public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("doing stuff");
    }
}
```

All this happend in master in several distinct operations (first move `AuthenticationService` to a new package and rename it, commit the changes, then use refactoring to introduce the interface thereby recreating `AuthenticationService.java` at the old place, and commit again).
When I now try to merge changes to the service classes made in another branch into master, git creates a lot of merge conflicts - basically I can manually resolve every single change to the service classes. I thought/hoped git would detect the rename operations and merge the changes made to the service classes into the service implementations (they are almost 100% identical to the old service classes), but it seems that git is happy with using the existing file and trying to merge it - failing completely.

Is there a way to force git to consider renames first? Or do I have to rename or move all service interfaces so that git doesn't find a candidate (which is something I'd like to avoid...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git merges based on *endpoints* (vs the merge-base).  Let's draw the commit graph:

```
... - B - R1 - R2   <-- HEAD=master
        \
          S1 - S2   <-- service
```

Here `B` is the merge-base (the point at which the two branches diverge), commit `R1` renames files, and commit `R2` reintroduces the old names.

Meanwhile, commits `S1` and `S2` are ordinary non-rename-y commits on the `service` (service classes) branch.

When you are on `master` and do `git merge service`, git effectively does this underneath:

```
git diff -M B R2 > our_changes
git diff -M B S2 > their_changes
# now combine the two sets of changes and make a new commit
```

The `-M` tries to detect renames, but is fooled because commit `R2` reintroduced the old file names.

There are two obvious (?) ways to make this merge automatically:

1. find the renames, make the same ones in `service`, and make a commit `S3` there so that the names match up (and then hope git doesn't accidentally detect those in comparing `B` to `S3` and make a mess), or;
2. do the merge incrementally.

I suspect (without trying it) that method 2 will work much better, plus you already did the work to separate out commits `R1` and `R2`, so you might as well use it.

To do this, check out commit `R1` (you can do this as a "detached HEAD" commit, or make a branch for it—let's call it `temp`, so you do `git checkout -b temp master^`), then `git merge service` to get a new merge commit.  This time, when git does the diff from `B` to `R1`, it should detect the renames, and apply the changes in the `service` branch to the renamed files (these are of course the *old*, unrefactored, files but that's pretty much what you have to do anyway, to get the changes to apply).  Now the graph looks like this:

```
               R2      <-- master
             /
... - B - R1 ---- M1   <-- HEAD=temp
        \        /
          S1 - S2      <-- service
```

You can now merge `temp` into `master` by doing `git checkout master; git merge temp`.  The merge-base for this merge is `R1`: git will look at what changed between `R1` and `M1`, and what changed between `R1` and `R2`, and attempt to bring the `R1 to M1` changes in on top of `R2`, making a new merge commit `M2`:

```
               R2 - M2 <-- HEAD=master
             /      /
... - B - R1 ---- M1   <-- temp
        \        /
          S1 - S2      <-- service
```

Since `M1` "captures" the renames (well, we hope), the changes in `S1` and `S2` are likely to land in the correct (old, pre-refactoring) files now.

---

The above assumes a specific number of commits, but the general idea is this: help git by choosing an earlier "endpoint" for the merge, where the rename-detection will do what you want.  Make a temporary branch for these merge results to go into.  Then use the merge result as input to a second merge.  (Repeat for more than two merges if needed.)  Remember to delete the temp branch names once you're done with them.